# How can I send specific messages to stdout from a bash prompt with multiple commands that is run via nohup?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, nohup

I want to run multiple commands that are concatenated via `&&` with nohup.
The output of the commands are redirected to `nohup.out` which is fine. But I want send some messages in between to stdout. Is that possible?

A simple example would be like:

```
nohup sh -c " \
echo some message 1 (to stdout) && \
some command 1 (to nohup.out) && \
echo some message 2 (to stdout) && \
some command 2 (to nohup.out) && \
..." &
```

I tried to to redirect the messages to stderr within the commands and then redirect stderr back to stdout:

```
nohup sh -c " \
echo some message 1 >&2 && \
some command 1 (to nohup.out) && \
echo some message 2 >$2 && \
some command 2 (to nohup.out) && \
..." 2>&1 &
```

But this did not work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by `stderr`? where do you think it goes for each of  your `nohup`, `sh`, `echo` and `some` commands?

Comment: My "goal" is, that the output of the commands goes to nohup.out and that the echo messages go to the console.

Comment: What do you mean by "to the console"? If you just want to send it to your terminal, why not redirecting those to `/dev/tty`?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, `nohup` redirects any output to `nohup.out`.

A simple workaround is to write somewhere else, and maybe have your shell display the contents of "somewhere else".

```
touch "$HOME"/.nohuplog
tail -f "$HOME"/.nohuplog &
nohup sh -c '
    exec 3>>"$HOME"/.nohuplog
    set -e # to avoid repeated "&&"
    echo "some message 1" >&3
    some command 1 (to nohup.out)
    echo "some message 2" >&3
    some command 2 (to nohup.out)
    ...' &
```

The `exec 3>...` so that you can use `>&3` and don't have to repeat `>>"$HOME"/.nohuplog` is just to make the code less repetitive.

You could use a FIFO instead of a file, or etc.

Maybe for improved usability add a `trap` to explain why the script exited in the case of an error. Bash offers the `ERR` pseudo-signal for `trap` for this purpose.

Alternatively, if you redirect standard output and/or standard error, no output will end up in `nohup.out`; this is frequently a better solution.

```
nohup sh -c '
    exec >>"$HOME"/.nohuplog
    exec 2>>"$HOME"/.nohuperr
    set -e # to avoid repeated "&&"
    echo "some message 1" >&2
    some command 1 (to nohup.out)
    echo "some message 2" >&2
    some command 2 (to nohup.out)
    ...' &
tail -f "$HOME"/.nohuplog "$HOME"/.nohuperr &
```

(Probably use a less generic file name for the destination files, too.)